# Test if all values in given set are turned on in SET type field for MySQL query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, bit-manipulation

I'm not seeing a clear and simple way to do this in a MySQL query.  The schema looks something like:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id VARCHAR(20),
    col SET('read', 'write', 'edit', 'delete'),
);
```

And if I wanted to query for all users with `read` and `write` privs (regardless of any other values set), the only query I have come up with to get the rows is:

```
SELECT id, privs
FROM users WHERE
FIND_IN_SET('read',privs) > 0 AND 
FIND_IN_SET('write',privs) > 0
```

Is there not some way to simplify this? Something like:

```
SELECT id, privs
FROM users WHERE
privs('read' & 'write')
```

Hypothetically, I'd like to use more sophisticated bit logic, but I want to know if the working example is the only way to accomplish this when using the `SET` type.

Answer (score 1):

Your values are stored in the same order like in your create table statement.

In your case:

```
        decimal   |   binary
read    1         |   0001
write   2         |   0010
edit    4         |   0100
delete  8         |   1000
```

You can get the decimal value by "converting" your column by adding a `0`.

So to get read&write you can do it like this:

```
SELECT id, privs
FROM users 
WHERE
privs+0 = 3;
```

Read more about it [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html)

UPDATE:

`privs+0 = 3` will return only "read&write".

Also like I said, the values will be stored in order, no matter how often a value gets assigned to an entry.

So you could also do it like this:

```
SELECT id, privs
FROM users 
WHERE
privs = 'read,write';
```

And if you want to have at least read & write and possible more:

```
SELECT id, privs
FROM users 
WHERE
privs LIKE 'read,write%';
```

Comment: Just to be clear, will this also work if all 4 flags are set but I want results where at least those 2 flags are set? Because I know that `privs+0 > 3` would return results where user had edit, even if they don't have read+write.

Comment: Also, is there not a clean way to pass it the privs I'm checking for? Something like `privs+0 = read & write`?

Answer (score 1):

If there's no elegant way to do that in MySQL, I will just settle for this, at least I don't need to manually memorize all the set elements bit fields positions/values, I still can use the more mnemonic strings. Will just use CROSS JOIN:

```
SELECT u.id, u.col
FROM users u

CROSS JOIN
(
  select sum(val) as bit_result from
  (
  SELECT 'read' as txt,1 as val
  union
  SELECT 'write' as txt,2 as val
  union
  SELECT 'edit' as txt,4 as val
  union
  SELECT 'delete' as txt,8 as val
  ) as x
  where txt in ('read','write')
) as z

WHERE u.col & z.bit_result = z.bit_result
```

source data:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id VARCHAR(20),
    col SET('read', 'write', 'edit', 'delete')
);

insert into users(id,col)
values ('hello','read,write');

insert into users(id,col)
values ('hola','read,delete,write');

insert into users(id,col)
values ('yeah','delete,write');
```

Outputs: 'hello' and 'hola'

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56070/41